# Understanding the basic principle of counting

Tags: probability

Suppose we perform $2$ experiments and this first experiment can result in any one of $m$ possible outcomes. Suppose the first experiment results in outcome $i$. Then, the second experiment can result in any of $n_i$ possible outcomes $i=1,..,m$. ${\bf Qs: } $ what is the number of possible outcomes of the two experiments?

#### Attempt:

If we have $1,...,m$ possible outcomes and say this experiment results in one of them say $i$. and so second experiment can result in $n_i$ for each $i$ so by multiplication principle we have $n_1 \cdot n_2 \cdot .. \cdot n_m$ possible outcomes. Is this correct?

Comment: Try it yourself with $m=2$ and $n_1=n_2=3$. Write down all possible results and count them. Do you get $9$ different possible results? If yes, then it is probable that your answer is true (you can test one or two other cases to be extra certain), and if no you're wrong (whether it's your formula or your list of outcomes which is faulty is more difficult to figure out).

Comment: You say that the second experiment can result in an outcome $n_1, n_2, n_3,\ldots$ or $n_m$. I don't understand this. What means "the outcome is n_5?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the outcomes implied by $n_1$ in the second experiment, we need outcome $1$ in the first experiment ($E_1=1$). Similarly we need outcome $E_1=2$ to get to those $n_2$ possibilities, etc.

So the possible second-experiment outcomes each depend on a given first-experiment result and the total outcome options are $\sum_1^m (1\cdot n_i) = \sum_1^m n_i$

Comment: This is entirely correct. However, you could've changed the $\sum$ into a $\prod$, and I suspect the OP wouldn't have noticed anything off. Maybe use a paragraph explaining why sum is correct and product is wrong?